# Bug in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>

Tags: c#, json.net

A strange bug had me beating my head.  To minimize traffic over the wire field names are mapped and deflated then inflated on the other end. If the field name is 'h' and the data is a datetime, the converter will crash with:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
{"Error converting value 9/29/2017 10:06:00 AM to type 'System.Double'. Path 'dSTD[0].h', line 1, position 293."} with an inner exception of Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Double'.

In the below c# sample, the first set of data (jsonDtA) crashes the converter, the second (jsonDtB) does not.

```
string jsonDtA = "{'dSTD':[{'v':'7ac36696-9977-4bf1-b211-1be2a01da04d','av':820210,'l':'72a9f721-86e0-4070-9cd9-dfa9d3c4efdd','ab':726943,'N':1,'A':'Y','B':'N','G':'N','E':'N','D':'N','K':0.0000,'O':1,'L':1.25,'H':1.25,'ac':'ProcessTransaction','ad':5,'ae':'2017-09-29T10:06:00','af':5,'h':'2017-09-29T10:06:00'}]}";
string jsonDtB = "{'dSTD':[{'v':'7ac36696-9977-4bf1-b211-1be2a01da04d','av':820210,'l':'72a9f721-86e0-4070-9cd9-dfa9d3c4efdd','ab':726943,'N':1,'A':'Y','B':'N','G':'N','E':'N','D':'N','K':0.0000,'O':1,'L':1.25,'H':1.25,'ac':'ProcessTransaction','ad':5,'ae':'2017-09-29T10:06:00','af':5,'hb':'2017-09-29T10:06:00'}]}";

DataSet dsA = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonDtA); 
DataSet dsB = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonDtB);
```

The ONLY difference is the name of the last datafield in the json set, 'h' vs. 'hb'

Of course my "fix" is to just not use 'h' in my deflation map...

The question is, why does this happen, and is it a bug?

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json v10.0.3

Comment: Looks like whatever you're deserializing the 'h' value to is a `double` not a `DateTime` which seems to be the issue. This is most likely not a bug in Json.NET but in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column names in `DataTable` objects are not case sensitive.  What is happening is that you've already got a column called `H` in your data, and the data type of that column is getting set to `double` due to the value `1.25`.  So when the `h` property comes along containing a date, Json.Net ends up trying to overwrite the original double value with it, which blows up due to the incompatible types.  By changing `h` to `hb` you avoid the problem because now all of your columns have unique names, as they should.

Here is a short fiddle which demonstrates the issue, taking Json.Net out of the equation entirely:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/bgmFsB

Comment: Thanks Brian. Coming from c# my brain assumes case sensitivity, my deflate and inflate was going for brevity so mixed caps and lower to keep character count down.  Works great for inflate/deflate but combined with case insensitive serialization it blew up. Thanks for screwing my head back on correctly ;)

Comment: No worries; it's not intuitive that DataTable column names should be case insensitive, and I couldn't find anything in the MS documentation which specifically states they are.  So the only way to confirm is by experimentation.  It probably goes back to the fact that DataTables are meant to mirror SQL tables, and those are case insensitive by default, at least in SQL Server.  Anyway, glad I could help solve the mystery.